# How do I add save popup through command? I am exporting scraped data in csv format

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, command-prompt, export-to-csv

I have written a script in PHP/Symfony which is scraping web data and saves it into a CSV file. I can save this CSV file in one of the folder on server. But I need output which goes to screen and whoever is running it choose where to save it.

```
class MiscScrapeHistoricalLeaseDataCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

protected function configure()
{
    parent::configure();
    $this->setName('abc:misc:scrape-lease-data');           
  
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{   
       // scrapper code
       ...........    
       $this->generateCsv($leaseData);
}

protected function generateCsv($leases = array()) {
       $output = fopen(getcwd().'/web/report.csv', 'w');
       fputcsv($output, array('Address', 'Square Foot', 'Tenant', 'Tenant Representativee', 'Landlord', 'Landlord Representative', 'Notes', 'Issue'));
       fclose($output);
     
} }
```

Comment: how about generating a download-link to the csv-report?

Comment: Right now I am just saving the exported csv file on server directory using $output = fopen(getcwd().'/web/leaseCSV/report.csv', 'w'); But I need to give option at user end to save and download the file.

Comment: i dont know symfony, but you need to create a link
<a href="/web/leaseCSV/report.csv">Download Report</a> for the end user, so he can click it an download it to his computer

Comment: Thank you Roeb for your suggestion.. I will try as per your suggestion.

Comment: I think providing link on command line is not the possible solution. Is there any other option?

Comment: ok ... so the code from above runs only on the server and doesnt produce html-output to the client? it is still the same - you need to offer your users a link to the location of the file

Comment: Yes Roeb. I am doing the same. Providing the link to user to download the file. Thank you for your help.